# Literal Control with dynamic title in control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add a dynamic title to a p tag and add it to the webpage with LiteralControl. The problem is that the occupants text that is added to the p tag only displays the first firstName.

```
foreach (var occ in occupants)
                {
                    occupants += occ.firstName + " " + occ.lastName + "<br/>";
                }

entryOccupants.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p title="+occupants+">Some Text</p>"));
```

This is what it looks like when viewing it with developer tools in chrome

```
<p title lastName data-original-title="firstName">Some Text</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have add the single quote for `title` attribute:

```
entryOccupants.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p title='"+occupants+"'>Some Text</p>"));
```

or you can use `string.Format()` to beautify your code:

```
entryOccupants.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("p title='{0}'>Some Text</p>", occupants)));
```